# How do you add an item to an existing cart using BigCommerce's Storefront Cart API?

Tags: fetch, bigcommerce

I'm having difficulty using the BigCommerce Storefront Cart API as described in their [docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/storefront-cart-api/cart/addcartlineitem)

When I manually send an http request through the fetch api using a console window open on the storefront website, it always comes back with 404 "Cart does not exist".

This is the fetch request I'm using:

```js
fetch(
  '/api/storefront/carts/e475da57-e9d1-4da0-b9bf-ac4c34b8d601/items',
  {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ lineItems: [{ quantity: 1, productId: 2968 }]}) 
  }
).then(res => res.json()).then(console.log)
```

I got the id by going to `<store-url>/api/storefront/cart`

When I simply do a GET on the same cart id, it sends back an object as expected.

I have no trouble when I make a new cart. It's only a problem if I want to add items to an existing cart.

I've tried adding a trailing forward slash, singular and plural forms of `carts` and `items` and `lineItems`

Comment: That's really odd--your code and API path look correct to me. This might sound silly, but are there definitely no typos in the Cart ID? Does the same thing happen if you delete the cart (by removing all of the items) and start over with a new cart?

Comment: If the Cart ID does not exist, it return a 404 error. Also, if the Product ID does not exist, it returns a 404 error. Can you verify that both are valid?

Comment: You need to use productVariantId, not productId